Global Matrix is almost empty, can't find modules
I'm trying to install a Genexus module from the global matrix (web extensions toolkit), but when I open it there are only two modules and not the one I'm looking for. I'm sure I got the module from there a few days ago, now it's gone. Did I misunderstand something? I'm working with the 17U10 version of genexus and the link of the global matrix is:
https://matrix-assets.genexus.com/repository/gx-global-matrix-stable-channel/

Did you try downloading it from Marketplace (https://marketplace.genexus.com/product.aspx?webextensionlibrary,en)?
According to the documentation (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?37807,Web+Extension+Toolkit), for version V17U5 or higher, Global Matrix should be used, and for version V17U4 and lower, Marketplace should be used. However, I couldn't find it on Global Matrix but found it on Marketplace. So, I assume that is a documentation issue.

In fact, then I downloaded it from there and it works, but the fact of having the global matrix with all the necessary modules is convenient, I would like to understand why it doesn't work well anymore

Components published on the Global Matrix are available depending on the GeneXus version you are using. Compatibility between the IDE version and the published component is checked.
I believe the issue is that the Extension Kit published on the Global Matrix is not compatible with V17. Therefore, if you try to install it from V17, it will not be available.
If you access the GM from V17 or from V18 you will see differents Components/versions
You can check all available modules at Global Matrix. https://matrix-assets.genexus.com/#browse/browse:gx-global-matrix-stable-channel:genexus
